# d3.js: formatting 500 million needs to display as 0.5G, but displays as 500mG

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I use this function to format numbers in my app, it's supposed to return a decimal number with a symbol, and accepts the max value to determine the symbol as well as the number to format as arguments:

```
function generateAmountAxis(maxVal){
      var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(maxVal);
      var format = d3.format(".2s");

      return function(number){
          return format(prefix.scale(number)) + prefix.symbol;
      }
 }
```

When I run it on a group of numbers:

```
generateAmountAxis(1000000000)(2000000000) // returns "2.0G"
generateAmountAxis(1000000000)(2100000000) // returns "2.1G"
generateAmountAxis(1000000000)(500000000) //returns "500mG" !!
```

my question is - why does it show 500mG for half a billion? i want it to show 0.5G

Answer (score 3):

you need to change your format

```
d3.format('.2s')
```

to

```
d3.format('.2')
```

(This may not be exact according to your requirement, as it would wrap 2.0 to 2, but you should know that the issue is with your format specifier)

see this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1639/

EDIT: you can use `d3.format('.1f')` for displaying results up to 1 floating point. see the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/1640/

For more information on formatters: http://koaning.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/html/d3format.html